# How to find value by data attribute in ASP Blazor like in jquery ($("#divID").attr("data-id"))?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using Blazor in a project. I am assigning data-id to each table row in foreach loop. Then I want to find/get each element by data-id when some one click on this table row. My question is that how can I use c# in blazor for this jquery statemetn like $("#tableRow1").attr("data-id").

Or just mentioned plz the best way to access DOM element by id, class, attribute. thanks

Comment: You attempt to reproduce the jquery programing style with Blazor. It is the wrong way. Click on tableRow could be handled by 100% pure C# code. There are many tuto's available to learn Blazor basics.

Comment: Yes you are right, we may do so with the help of c#. But I just want can we do so using jQuery

Comment: Please reconsider your question after minimal comprehension of the Blazor concepts. In Blazor, DOM access is « reserved » to Blazor update mechanisms. Working directly on the DOM may give unattended results. It is not in the Blazor spirit to work with a JavaScript framework and consequently mostly with JS interop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the JS Interop functionality should allow you to get the values of a particular element by ID.

[Here is the MS documentation regarding this feature.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

The flow would be something like:

1. Setup a JS interop function that takes a component reference object.  This function will grab all table rows by class name.
2. Set an 'on-click' event that will grab the ID of the row that was clicked.
3. Have the event handler send the ID back to the c# component by calling a c# function passed via the component reference object.

Setting up the component reference object:

```
private DotNetObjectReference<YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME> objRef;
    
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    //objRef gives our JS Interop functions the ability to call c# methods (and do other things)
    //that are specific to this component instance.
    objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
}
```

We then pass this object when calling the initial JS Interop function:

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("InteropFunctions.getAllRowsAndSetListener", objRef);
    }
}
```

JS Interop function example:

```
window.InteropFunctions = {    
getAllRowsAndSetListener: (componentObjRef) => {
    let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tableRow");

    if (rows.length) {
        rows.forEach(row => row.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            await componentObjRef.invokeMethodAsync("DoSomethingWithId", e.target.id);
        }))
    }
}}
```

C# method in component that will take the ID and do something:

```
[JSInvokable]
public void DoSomethingWithId(string id)
{
    // ... do something with ID
}
```

It should be noted that you can pass anything back to the C# method as long as its JSON serializable.  So you could pass back typed objects, arrays, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much muddy beard. I got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe be you should mark it as the correct answer then, @Noor Uddin?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer (and the question) are a little backwards. No JS is needed. Blazor uses more of a model-view setup, where the rendering reflects the model.

That being said, you can simply reference your own data inside the loop and pass parameters to a click handler.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in rows}
        {
            <tr><td @onclick="@(()=>OnClick(row.Id))">@row.Title</td>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code{
   ...
   private void OnClick(int id)
   {
      // Do something about the specific Id clicked
   }
   ...
}
```

You can also pass the actual row data instead of just the id if you prefer.

Note: The extra `@` and `()` around the `()=>OnClick(row.id)` are needed for it to recognise it is a lambda expression